# what is the browser version and operation system of this iis log entry

Tags: iis

Mozilla/5.0+(Windows;+U;+Windows+NT+5.1;+en-US;+rv:1.9.2.11)+Gecko/20101012+Firefox/3.6.11+(+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser: Firefox/3.6.11

OS: Windows NT 5.1 = Windows XP

Comment: Windows NT 5.1 or Windows XP?

Comment: See that little = sign I put there? They are one and the same.

Comment: there was never Windows NT 5.1, "NT" is seen as the kernel "family", and the version has been incremented with each Windows release (2000, XP, Vista, 7, etc)

Comment: -1 for the Google quip. Are your flagging and vote to close tools broken?